# WebSphere 6.1 - periodically log number of HTTP sessions

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, websphere-6.1

We're running an older J2EE application on WebSphere 6.1 Express.  There are periods where users are complaining of slow response times.  I suspect this is because the server has a lot of active sessions at the time.  I'd like to be able to justify getting a bigger server with more RAM to handle the load.  When I go into the Tivoli Performance Viewer and enable Servlet Session Manager, which will show me the Live Count of all active sessions.  What I'd like to do is write this number out to the SystemOut.log (or another log file via Log4J) every five minutes.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot write it to the SystemOut.log by default. In general you have the following options:

- For short/medium periods of time you can enable logging in PMI - [Configuring TPV settings](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_6.1.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/info/iseriesnd/ae/tprf_tpvsettings.html?lang=en)
- Install PerfServletApp and use [perfservlet](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_6.1.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tprf_devprfservlet.html?lang=en) to get statistics in xml form via http. But you would have to parse and store it by yourself.
- You can use [WebSphere Performance Tuning Toolkit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/performtuning.html) available for free either as separate download (older version) or as plugin to ISA (IBM Support Assistant) to monitor and visualize PMI statistics.
- Or you can develop your custom PMI client - see [Using the JMX interface to develop your own monitoring application](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSAW57_6.1.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tprf_pmijmx.html)

Comment: The "Using the JMX interface to develop your own monitoring application" and this article "Websphere in memory session count"  [link](http://websphereadmin-janglestrategies.blogspot.com/2010/02/websphere-in-memory-session-count.html) provided the necessary clues.  I'll post my Java-based solution here once its finished.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak If you want to create custom solution the best is to implement it as Custom service, and configure on server. In this way you don't need to deploy and run any additional application. Check here how to create and configure custom service - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/trun_customservice.html?lang=en